# ES6 jQuery bind listener as anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

i want to bind an anonymous function to a jQuery event listener inside an ES6 class.

Something like:

```
class MyClass{    
    constructor(){
        $( document ).mousedown( callAnonymous );
    }    
    callAnonymous(e){
        //Need class references here
    }
}
```

Is there a simple syntax for this? Couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: What anonymous function are you talking about? There is none in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You would bind it like you would any normal function:

```js
$(document).mousedown(this.callAnonymous.bind(this));
```

Comment: so with .bind(this) i still have class references in my handlerfunc?

Comment: Yes, that's what binding does. If you bind it to `this`, then the `this` inside `callAnonymous` will refer to the class instance.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: it would have to be `this.callAnonymous.bind(this)`. `callAnonymous` is a property of the class instance.